# Что такое суррогатные пары?

Tags: javascript, терминология

Что такое суррогатные пары?

Прочитал вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986614/what-is-a-surrogate-pair), но все равно не понял.

И почему длина элемента равна 2, а цикл `for of` выводит только один элемент?

```js
const str = "";

console.log(str.length); // 2

for(let key of str){
  console.log(key) // 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5903008/6104996

Answer (score 1):

Такие символы записываются двумя 16-битными словами, поэтому длина - 2.
Но символ-то один.
Можно здесь посмотреть информацию https://learn.javascript.ru/string